# My visa got refused despite showing healthy sponsor bank statements as well as my bank statements

Tags: uk, paperwork, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK visit visa two weeks ago and it got rejected on the basis that I had not submitted my own bank statement. I did submit the bank statements of my employer as my employer was sending me to the UK to its sister company to train staff there. I submitted bank statements of both these companies and explicitly stated that these two will sponsor me jointly. However, they still rejected my visa on the basis that I didnt submit my bank statements. I applied again last week, this time adding my bank statement. However, it got rejected again, saying I dont have funds as well as more reasons. Can someone help me out? [image]

Comment: What exactly are the family ties referred to in the third paragraph of the refusal letter? Do you have any family in the UK? Did your employer provide you with an invitation letter? Where is your employer based and why do they need to send someone from India to train UK-based colleagues? This question explains why personal bank statements are important https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: I do have a spouse but no children yet. I also have both parents alive as well as a couple of siblings. Their National Identity Cards were submitted as well. I even submitted a Notarized Marriage Certificate, showing evidence of my marriage. I have no relatives in the UK and I mentioned the same in the application. 

As far as deposits are concerned, I do not deposit the full 22k in my bank account as I get my salary via cash. I had submitted my cash voucher given by my employer as proof of salary.

Comment: @whizbangkray IMHO after two refusals you’re not going to get a UK visa any time soon. Think of it from UKVI’s point of view: how easily could business-related training in a sister company *in the UK* turn into an opportunity to overstay, enabling you to support your family from afar? You could try submitting your most recent tax return, and you could get all your salary paid into your account instead of part in cash. But unless your employer is eg a large company with a good track record of sending employees to the UK for the purposes you describe, I suspect you’re on a highway to nowhere.

Answer (score 11):

You are misinterpreting what they write. They don't have any concerns pertaining to the funding for your trip. They acknowledge the information you provided regarding sponsorship by your employer and the UK sponsor, and express no complaints about this part.

The part where they have concerns is whether your life in India is a) as you describe and b) a sufficient reason for you to return home after your trip. For example, your bank statement should support your claim that your salary is what it is, and it does not. If your financial affairs are not such that you receive a regular salary into your bank account, it tends to be much harder to get a UK visa. Again, this is not about having money, this is about having orderly and transparent financial affairs.

A part probably at least as important as the bank statements is the issue of your dependents. I assume that you mention having some dependents (maybe children? elderly parents? underage siblings?). If these dependents remain in India, they'd be a reason for you to return. They thus want evidence that these people exist, remain in India, and really depend on you (the latter would probably be quite straightforward for children, but needs substantial evidence for everyone else). This dependence would often also show on your account statements, but also other evidence might be appropriate/necessary.

Comment: I do have a spouse but no children yet. I also have both parents alive as well as a couple of siblings. Their National Identity Cards were submitted as well. I even submitted a Notarized Marriage Certificate, showing evidence of my marriage. I have no relatives in the UK and I mentioned the same in the application. 

As far as deposits are concerned, I do not deposit the full 22k in my bank account as I get my salary via cash. I had submitted my cash voucher given by my employer as proof of salary.

Comment: @whizbangkray Cash salary payments are suspicious at best. You should've never agreed to that. Have it all deposited in full and then withdrawing it would've been much better as proof of record. Right now, it shows irregular transfers at best.

Answer (score 5):

They don’t ask for bank statements only to determine if you can afford the trip (which is irrelevant if someone else pays), but also to assess your ties to your home country, and a layer of cross-verification of the other information you provided.

The goal of the officer reviewing your visa application is to determine that you are more likely to leave the UK at the end of your visa than to stay in the UK.

Positive points are things like a stable job with a good salary (the higher the better), having dependents (spouse, children) and other relatives in your home country, having your own place to live and even better owning it, etc.

Negative points include not having a job or a very low paid job, having family or relatives in the UK which could help or even be a reason for you to stay there, etc.

Just for context: 22000 INR at this time is 210 GBP, which is less than 15% of the **minimum** monthly wage in the UK for someone working full time. There is thus a strong incentive for you to stay and work in the UK, even if off the books and under the official minimum, so you may have little reason to go back to your country when your visa ends just to get back to your current work.

Now this could be enough if they were convinced you have this job, that it is stable, that you do earn that amount, and that you have more other reasons to return home than to stay in the UK.

Initially you didn’t provide any bank statements, so they couldn’t confirm anything, and this led to a refusal.

Next you submitted documents, but apparently they do not quite match your declarations. Do your statements show 22000 INR being deposited each month? Do the outgoings match your other declarations?

Finally, you have the issue of family. It’s not clear from your question what the situation is? Do you have a spouse and children? Where do they live? Do you have other relatives (parents, siblings, cousins, etc.) who live in the UK?

Remember: by default, a consular officer or a border officer start with the presumption that you want to immigrate and will overstay. It is up to you to convince them you won’t, with factual evidence of your ties to your country giving your more reasons to come back than to overstay.

Comment: I do have a spouse but no children yet. I also have both parents alive as well as a couple of siblings. Their National Identity Cards were submitted as well. I even submitted a Notarized Marriage Certificate, showing evidence of my marriage. I have no relatives in the UK and I mentioned the same in the application. 

As far as deposits are concerned, I do not deposit the full 22k in my bank account as I get my salary via cash. I had submitted my cash voucher given by my employer as proof of salary.